Uncaught TypeError: $frames.filter(...).sort is not a function
I am Using jquery 4.0.0 beta 2 i get a error:

Uncaught TypeError: $frames.filter(...).sort is not a function

because the .sort() is removed from jquery.
It is part of the fotorama.js which is no longer supported. Any idea how to fix this?
   function frameAppend ($frames, $shaft, type) {
    if (!frameAppend[type]) {

      var thumbsFLAG = type === 'nav' && o_navThumbs,
          left = 0;

      $shaft.append(
        $frames
            .filter(function () {
              var actual,
                  $this = $(this),
                  frameData = $this.data();
              for (var _i = 0, _l = data.length; _i < _l; _i++) {
                if (frameData.data === data[_i]) {
                  actual = true;
                  frameData.eq = _i;
                  break;
                }
              }
              return actual || $this.remove() && false;
            })
            .sort(function (a, b) {
              return $(a).data().eq - $(b).data().eq;
            })
            .each(function () {

              if (!thumbsFLAG) return;

              var $this = $(this),
                  frameData = $this.data(),
                  thumbwidth = Math.round(o_thumbSide2 * frameData.data.thumbratio) || o_thumbSide;

              frameData.l = left;
              frameData.w = thumbwidth;

              $this.css({width: thumbwidth});

              left += thumbwidth + opts.thumbmargin;
            })
      );

      frameAppend[type] = true;
    }
  }


The solution to this problem is to split the code. Bring the .filter and .code outside the $shaft.append();
      function frameAppend ($frames, $shaft, type) {
    if (!frameAppend[type]) {

        var thumbsFLAG = type === 'nav' && o_navThumbs,
          left = 0;

        $frames.filter(function () {
              var actual,
                  $this = $(this),
                  frameData = $this.data();
              for (var _i = 0, _l = data.length; _i < _l; _i++) {
                if (frameData.data === data[_i]) {
                  actual = true;
                  frameData.eq = _i;
                  break;
                }
              }
              return actual || $this.remove() && false;
        });
        [].sort.call( $frames, function (a, b) {
              return $(a).data().eq - $(b).data().eq;
        });

        $shaft.append(
            $frames
                .each(function () {

                  if (!thumbsFLAG) return;

                  var $this = $(this),
                      frameData = $this.data(),
                      thumbwidth = Math.round(o_thumbSide2 * frameData.data.thumbratio) || o_thumbSide;

                  frameData.l = left;
                  frameData.w = thumbwidth;

                  $this.css({width: thumbwidth});

                  left += thumbwidth + opts.thumbmargin;
                })
        );
        frameAppend[type] = true;
    }
  }

